# How to enable headless mode for Opera using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, opera, headless

For Chrome and others you can just do:

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True
```

However, for Opera that doesn't seem to work, even though Opera is based on Chromium now and even uses the ChromeOptions for configuration. What do I need to change to enable headless mode?

Comment: A trivial Google search seems to suggest headless mode for Opera is not supported. Maybe throw a like on this: https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/issues/62